# Несколько значений в одном поле.

Tags: mysql

Как лучше хранить несколько значений в одном поле mySQL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте про [нормализацию баз данных](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0), и, в частности, про [Первую нормальную форму](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) и постарайтесь понять, что люди придумали это не просто так

Comment: Если бы я был способен это прочесть и главное понять ... Я бы отвечал на Ваши вопросы а не Вы на мои :) Примеры гораздо более наглядны чем сложный и непонятный текст. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: А еще захотелось познакомиться с Вашими творениями. Поможете?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем так делать? Чем вам отношения "один ко многим" не угодили? По теме: varchar поле, значения перечисляются через специальные разделители. Разделители выбираются в зависимости от того, что вы собираетесь хранить. Например, можно использовать `;`, `|`, пробелы.